# Scoped Validations in Has Many Through Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a has_many through: association between `Token` and `User` using `UserToken` as the join model. I would like to have a `validate_uniqueness_of` on  the `device_name` attribute of the Token model scoped to a specific User.

Meaning, I would only want to validate device_name uniqueness if there is already a Token record created for that User with the same device_name. Normally one would be able to just do this: `validates_uniqueness_of :device_name, scope: :user_id` however user_id is not an attribute of Token, this attribute is in the join table... I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create this validation in Rails. I know you can do at the DB level with an index but I would like to do it via validations if possible. Any thoughts?

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_tokens
   has_many :users, through: :user_tokens

   validates_uniqueness_of :device_name, scope: #only validate if there is already a Token for this user with this device_name.
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_tokens
   has_many :tokens, through: :user_tokens
end

class UserToken < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :token
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you wouldn't be able to access the `user_id` attribute with the built-in validation helpers in the `Token` model, using custom validators may be something that could provide you with more flexibility to achieve the validation you're looking for:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by creating the following custom validation.

```
validate :unique_device_name_per_user?

def unique_device_name_per_user?
  user = User.find(user_tokens.first.user_id)
  token = user.tokens.where(device_name: device_name)

  if token.present?
    self.errors.add(:device_name, ": This user has already registered this device_name.")
  end
end
```